# Problem with my Docker image not running Flask

Tags: docker, flask

I am trying to build a Flask docker image. I get the error:

> zsh: command not found: flask

I followed this old tutorial to get things working. https://medium.com/@rokinmaharjan/running-a-flask-application-in-docker-80191791e143

In order to just learn how to start flask website with Docker I have made everything simple. My Docker image should just open a Hello world front page.

My example.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return 'Hello World'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install python -y
RUN apt-get install python-pip -y
RUN pip install flask
COPY example.py /home/example.py
ENTRYPOINT FLASK_APP=/home/example.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

I run

> sudo docker build . -t flask-app

to build the image.

When I run

> docker run -p 8080:5000 flask-app

I get the error:

> zsh: command not found: flask

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your Docker image doesn't contain `zsh` at all; it won't be the standard shell or even installed on the `ubuntu:16.04` base image.  Is something on your host setup reinterpreting that command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, indeed you're following a really old tutorial.

I'm not going to enter into detail whether using Flask directly without a WSGI server is something you should do, so I'm just going to focus on your question.

**Concise answer:** you don't have the installed modules by `pip` in your `PATH`, so of course you cannot invoke them. Flask is one of this modules.

**Extended answer:** keep reading.

---

First of all, using that base image you're downloading an old version of both Python and `pip`, secondary: you don't need a fully fledged operative system in order to run a Flask application. There are already base images with Python like `python:3.9.10-slim-buster` with way less dependencies and possible vulnerabilities than an old image from Ubuntu 16.

```
FROM python:3.9.10-slim-buster
```

Second, you shouldn't rely on what do you have on the base image and you should use an environment (`venv`) for your application, where you can install Flask and any other dependency of the application which should be listed on the `requirements.txt`. Also you should choose in which working directory you would like to place your code (`/usr/src/app` is a common place normally).

Indicating which port are you exposing by default is also a good thing to do (even though everyone knows that Flask exposes port 5000).

```
FROM python:3.9.10-slim-buster

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

RUN python3 -m pip install flask
COPY example.py .
ENTRYPOINT FLASK_APP=example flask run --host=0.0.0.0

EXPOSE 5000
```

and as a result:

```
❯ docker run -p 8080:5000 flask-app
 * Serving Flask app 'example' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: Thank you for such a through answer. I'm going to play around with this and mark it correct once it works on my machine.

Comment: Running the docker image works but when visiting the page 172.17.0.2:5000/ it does not load anything. I get a connection timed out error. Is there something I might be missing on my Macbook?

Comment: Another question I have is how do you figure this out? I have been looking at tutorials for a week now and none of them worked. Hence why I finally asked on here. My goal is to ultimately figure this stuff out on my own and answer other people's questions on here. What is your thought process on the solution to this problem?

Comment: In a Docker container you often don't need a virtual environment since the Docker image itself is isolation from other Pythons and applications.  It's routine to `RUN pip install` into the "system" Python, and when you do, Pip should put the Python entry point scripts (like `flask`) into `/usr/local/bin` or somewhere else accessible.

Comment: Hello @Funlamb, regarding the port: which port are you mapping when you use `docker run` and which one are you trying to access in the host machine? Regarding on how do I figure it out, instead of looking for tutorials on how to deploy Flask or any other technology in Docker, I'd just look for a good Docker tutorial which covers all the fundamentals. After that, the documentation under the Dockerfile reference is more than enough. Also, I have an article about dockerized Python applications: https://snyk.io/blog/best-practices-containerizing-python-docker/, feel free to take a look.

Comment: @DavidMaze that's partially true. Meanwhile it's true that in this specific case she could just install it, it's a good practice to learn about `venv` usage in Docker as soon as possible, as the desired scenario will always be to use a multi-stage Dockerfile where the deployment uses a different base image than the build, and it's interesting that learning people start with this kind of practices.

Comment: @DanielCampos I found my mistake for loading the webpage. I tried to fallow the `Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` when I should have been fallowing the port I used to open up the docker container. 

As far as making containers on my own I have watched and learned the fundamentals about Docker. I think my lack of understanding comes from not knowing how to build servers outside of Docker. I will keep learning everything I can until I can figure out what I need to learn from the documentation pages.